# sphinx not linking to multiprocessing.Value

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I am using Sphinx to document a small project I am working on.  I am using Python multiprocessing Queue and Value constructs, and I want Sphinx to link to the correct documentation.  I am quite new to using Sphinx, so I am having trouble understanding what I may be doing wrong.

I have these two lines in my code, the link to Queue works correctly and links [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) As expected.  But the second one, which should link [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) Does not.

:type param1: :class:`~multiprocessing.Queue`

:type param2: :method:`~multiprocessing.Value` (Also tried with :class:, :function:, :attribute:)

Both of these are in the docstring of the function, and sphinx is correctly generating the rest of it as I expect, only problem is that it isn't linking to the multiprocessing.Value documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Value` is a function and the proper cross-reference role is [`:func:`](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects). The following markup should work for you:

```
:type param2: :func:`~multiprocessing.Value`
```

Comment: I see, yes that worked.  I suppose I was confused with what a method is.  :meth: is for a method of an object, multiprocessing is not an object :)  Thanks.